# Mongodump invalid JSON input

Tags: linux, mongodb-query, mongodump

I tried running this command in a Linux machine:

```bash
mongodump --host "abcd" -p=27 -u "y" -p "xx" --out /c -d "t" --gzip -c "t" --query { "Cli" : "c", "Mar" : "A" ,"F":{"$gte":ISODate("2022-01-01")}}
```

Unfortunately, the call fails with this error:

```
 Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input. Position: XX. Character: $
```

I tried changing the ISODATE to `ISODate("2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")` but with no luck.

The mongodb version is 5.0.14 and tools version is 6.1.100.

Comment: You should use [extended json syntax](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)